# how to implement soap receiver for saop envelope message c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, web, soap, service

how to implement soap receiver for saop envelope message c#
i'm integrating my app with old system that should response to my system as call back response .
my web service should receive this soap message

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"> 
   <soapenv:Header> 
      <ns1:NotifySOAPHeader xmlns:ns1="http://www.huawei.com.cn/schema/common/v2_1"> 
         <ns1:traceUniqueID>504021505821207281129180006002</ns1:traceUniqueID> 
      </ns1:NotifySOAPHeader> 
   </soapenv:Header> 
   <soapenv:Body> 
      <ns2:processRequest xmlns:ns2="http://b2b.mobilemoney.mtn.zm_v1.0/"> 
         <serviceId>101</serviceId> 
         <parameter> 
            <name>ProcessingNumber</name> 
            <value>12121212</value> 
         </parameter> 
         <parameter> 
            <name>senderID</name> 
            <value>MOM</value> 
         </parameter> 
         <parameter> 
            <name>AcctRef</name> 
            <value>112233</value> 
         </parameter> 
         <parameter> 
            <name>RequestAmount</name> 
            <value>1212</value> 
         </parameter> 
         <parameter> 
            <name>paymentRef</name> 
            <value>12121</value> 
         </parameter> 
         <parameter> 
            <name>ThirdPartyTransactionID</name> 
            <value>12112</value> 
         </parameter> 
         <parameter> 
            <name>MOMAcctNum</name> 
            <value>121212</value> 
         </parameter> 
         <parameter> 
            <name>CustName</name> 
            <value>121212</value> 
         </parameter> 
         <parameter> 
            <name>TXNType</name> 
            <value>12121</value> 
         </parameter> 
         <parameter> 
            <name>StatusCode</name> 
            <value>12121</value> 
         </parameter> 
         <parameter> 
            <name>OpCoID</name> 
            <value>0</value> 
         </parameter> 
      </ns2:processRequest> 
   </soapenv:Body> 
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

how to build web-service that accept this soap message

Comment: "web-service" is a vague term, what exactly is your "service"? The answer from BRAHIM may be on the right track, but there is no reason to do any string manipulations. Also, if the service exposes its metadata you can try adding a Service Reference to your project and it will do all the hard work - but it is unclear which service is calling who.

Comment: @Crowcoder I'm doing a string manipulation just to  omit the issue of namespace manipulation  that's it and I think that in term of performance is much better than doing this  on xml elements

Comment: @BRAHIMKamel, that is what `XNamespace` is for. And if you can't rely on it being consistent, you can always use `XName.LocalName`

Comment: @BRAHIMKamel I respectfully disagree that a bunch of indexing and substrings and `Replace` is KISS, xml has a rich api and IMO it should be used. Also, this is xml, not JSON.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try the following

- Declare your callback as a post http method
- Take the body of your request and deserialze it to POO

in your controller

```
  [HttpPost]
        Public async Task<IHttpActionResult> ProcessRequest(string saopRequest)
        {   //here just a bit of string manipulation 
           var index = soapRequest.IndexOf("<ns2:processRequest");
                var lasindex = soapRequest.IndexOf("</ns2:processRequest>");
                var length = lasindex - index +"</ns2:processRequest>".Length  ;           
                var body = soapRequest.Substring(index,length);
                var request = body.Replace("ns2:", string.Empty).Replace("xmlns:ns2=\"http://b2b.mobilemoney.mtn.zm_v1.0/\"",string.Empty);

                XDocument xResult = XDocument.Parse(request);


                XmlSerializer deserializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(ProcessRequest), new XmlRootAttribute("processRequest"));
                if (xResult.Root != null)
                {
                    var finalRequest= (ProcessRequest)deserializer.Deserialize(xResult.Root.CreateReader());
                    //do what you  want here 
                }                
        }



        [XmlRoot(ElementName="parameter")]
        public class Parameter {
            [XmlElement(ElementName="name")]
            public string Name { get; set; }
            [XmlElement(ElementName="value")]
            public string Value { get; set; }
        }

        [XmlRoot(ElementName="processRequest")]
        public class ProcessRequest {
            [XmlElement(ElementName="serviceId")]
            public string ServiceId { get; set; }
            [XmlElement(ElementName="parameter")]
            public List<Parameter> Parameter { get; set; }      
        }
}
```